# как открыть один файл сразу в двух окнах Sublime3

Tags: sublime-text-3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]как открыть один и тот же файл сразу в двух окнах Sublime3

Comment: `alt+shift+1...7`

Comment: не количество окон, а один и тот же файл в двух окнах

Comment: На Тостере [**я отвечал**](https://toster.ru/answer?answer_id=873422#answers_list_answer) на этот вопрос. По ссылке подробный ответ и GIF-демонстрация. Спасибо.

Comment: Да, то, что у Вас на изображении, в терминологии Sublime Text называется не «окнами» — windows, а «panes» — «областями». Если Вам нужно открыть файл в двух «областях», а не «окнах», то см. мой ответ по ссылке выше.

Comment: Попробуйте так File | New View into File https://stackoverflow.com/a/21992285/9046811

Comment: Проще и быстрее всего создать новый файл в новой вкладке и скопировать туда содержимое Вашего файла.

Answer (score 1):

Использовать меню File / New View into File. В одном из окон создастся копия файла, которую можно будет перетащить в другое окно.

Answer (score 0):

Откройте два разных файла в вашем `Sublime`, перетащите одну вкладку на рабочий стол, она выйдет в отдельное окно. Затем перетащите файл который вам нужен, в первое, а затем и во второе окно, закройте не нужные вкладки, и у вас будет открыт один файл в двух окнах.

Comment: Много действий. Легче нажать один шорткат. Спасибо.